# Android: Creating user specified # of progress bars in the layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

//this is where I want the progressbars to be.
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to create user specified number of progress bars in the layout programmatically without having to specifying it in the xml file. Please help me figure out this.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can't re-write a layout file at runtime but you could put a 'place-holder' layout in the XML file and then add progress bars to it programmatically at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest placing a container for these progressbars (really any widget) ex

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linBars"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your code, namely in your activity (essentially you need access to a `Context` object) Keep in mind I gave the container the id 'linBars'. This can be any valid Java identifier (it gets put into R.id.)

```
 //Get the container
 LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linBars);


 ProgressBar pbar = new ProgressBar(this);
 //Set any properties for it here (eg setInterpolator etc)
 container.addView(pbar); //ProgressBar and just about any widget is a subclass of View
```

I'd suggest reading up on [ViewGroups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) which is where most of the 'add/remove a widget to a container' code is at. `LinearLayout` is a subclass of it, you could also use some others, but its probably the best for a bunch of `ProgressBar` instances.

To answer your comment *How do I refer the created widget?*

Two ways with their own pros and cons

- Create a list or an array to hold your widgets and either before or after you add them to the `LinearLayout` add them to the list/array. You can refer to them all you would like, except you need to clean house in your `OnDestroy` and remove all references to them or your program will eat up memory and if it calls something on a widget whose parent is destroyed it will either do nothing or explode (aka throw an exception).
- `ViewGroup` will actually let you access any and all widgets underneath it. Unfortunately, you are given no guarantees as to what order or what type of widget you retrieve. Methods for this are [`getChildAt(int index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and `getChildCount()`. Keep in mind it returns a `View` object so only if you know for sure all the children are of a certain type you can safely cast it. The other caveat as described in the SDK link I gave for it, it will return null if there's no child at the index you specified. In our example we know all the views added are `ProgressBar` so we can do something like below

Example getting all progress bars:

```
  //Get the container
  LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linBars);

  ProgressBar pbar;
  for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
      pbar = (ProgressBar) container.getChildAt(i);
      //Do whatever to the progress bar here
  }
```

I feel I must also point out another issue. If the user leaves the app (ie hits home button, gets a phone call) and after some time the system decides to destroy the activity to save memory and then the user navigates back to your app the progress bars will be gone unless you save info to reconstruct them in the `Bundle` during `OnDestroy` and check in your `OnCreate` for items in the `Bundle` to then re-add to your `linearLayout`.

Comment: How do I refer the created widget? Any Idea?